# Camuflando endereço remetente num e-mail em PHP

Tags: php

Eu não consigo camuflar o endereço do remetente *@qualquercoisa.com*, eu sou obrigado a usar o do meu domínio, mas no meu script de envio que eu perdi dava para camuflar, porem eu acho que isso é coisa da hospedagem eu uso kinghost, da outra vez eu não usava a kinghost e não passei trabalho para fazer, tanto que botei no meu código lá, só que quando entra na condição da parte de por o nome que eu quiser, se eu por, não aceita, parece que a hospedagem bloqueia o envio do email, deve ser né, ou tem algum método ???

**O código de enviar o html é:**

```
function sendmail() {
    if(!isset($_POST[Submit])) die("Não foi recebido nenhum parâmetro");
    /* Medida preventiva para evitar que outros domínios sejam remetente da sua mensagem. */
    if (eregi('tempsite.ws$|locaweb.com.br$|hospedagemdesites.ws$|websiteseguro.com$', $_SERVER[HTTP_HOST])) {
            $emailsender=trim($_POST['emailremetente']);
    } else {
            $emailsender = "noreply@" . $_SERVER[HTTP_HOST];
    }

    /* Verifica qual é o sistema operacional do servidor para ajustar o cabeçalho de forma correta. Não alterar */
    if(PHP_OS == "Linux") $quebra_linha = "\n";
    elseif(PHP_OS == "WINNT") $quebra_linha = "\r\n";
    else die("Incompatibilidade com Sistema Operacional");

    // Passando os dados obtidos pelo formulário para as variáveis abaixo
    $nomeremetente     = $_POST['nomeremetente'];
    $emailremetente    = trim($_POST['emailremetente']);
    $assunto           = $_POST['assunto'];

    $array_emaildestinatario = array();
    $array_emaildestinatario = explode("\n",trim($_POST['emaildestinatario'])); // separa os emails pelas vírgulas em uma array
    foreach($array_emaildestinatario as $elemento) {
        //pra cada email envia
        /* Montando a mensagem a ser enviada no corpo do e-mail. */
        $mensagemHTML = html();


        /* Montando o cabeçalho da mensagem */
        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.1".$quebra_linha;
        $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1".$quebra_linha;
        // Perceba que a linha acima contém "text/html", sem essa linha, a mensagem não chegará formatada.
        $headers .= "From: ".$emailsender.$quebra_linha;
        $headers .= "Return-Path: " . $emailsender . $quebra_linha;

        $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$emailremetente.$quebra_linha;
        // Note que o e-mail do remetente será usado no campo Reply-To (Responder Para)

        /* Enviando a mensagem */
        mail($elemento, $assunto, $mensagemHTML, $headers, "-r". $emailsender);
    }
    /* Mostrando na tela as informações enviadas por e-mail */
    ?>
        <div style="color:white;border:1px solid black;padding:15px;background-color:rgba(150,50,50,0.8);font-family:Arial;margin-bottom:5px;font-size:14px;">
            Enviando <?php echo count($array_emaildestinatario); ?> e-mails, aguarde um instante...
        </div>
        <div style="color:white;border:1px solid black;padding:15px;background-color:rgba(150,50,50,0.8);font-family:Arial;margin-bottom:5px;font-size:14px;">
            De:<?php echo $emailsender; ?>
        </div>
        <div style="color:white;border:1px solid black;padding-left:15px;padding-top:5px;padding-bottom:5px;background-color:rgba(150,50,50,0.3);font-family:Arial;margin-bottom:5px;font-size:14px;">
        <?php 
        foreach($array_emaildestinatario as $elemento) {
            echo "<p>$elemento</p>";
        }
        ?>
        </div>
<?php
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deverás falar com o [suporte técnico da KingHost](http://www.kinghost.com.br/fale-conosco) para obter uma resposta exata à tua pergunta, mas pelo que vejo na [FAQ para configuração do email](http://www.kinghost.com.br/perguntas-e-respostas-faq#configurar_email), o envio de emails requer autenticação o que é indicativo do servidor não ser *Open Email Relay*.

### Servidor que não permite *Relay*

Ao enviar emails, poder-se-á receber uma mensagem de erro a dar conta que o email não pode ser enviado devido a um bloqueio de retransmissão (*relay*) por parte do servidor SMTP (*Simple Mail Transfer Protocol*).

A mensagem de erro exata pode variar, dependendo do servidor mas essencialmente diz-me que o servidor não permite *relay*, sendo necessário autenticação para proceder ao envio do email e/ou estar a utilizar uma conta existente no servidor para esse efeito.

### Servidor *Open Email Relay*

O que tu estás a tentar fazer requer um servidor configurado como [Open Email Relay](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mail_relay):

> An open mail relay is an SMTP server configured in such a way that it allows anyone on the Internet to send e-mail through it.

Que traduzido:

> Um open mail relay é um servidor SMTP configurado de tal forma que permite que qualquer pessoa na Internet possa enviar e-mails através dele.

---

### Notas:

De servidor para servidor as configurações mudam significativamente, mas o comum é o *Relay* não ser permitido pois acarreta muito problema de segurança e SPAM o que baixa a reputação do servidor em si.

Configurações intermédias também se encontram onde o envio dos emails é feito sem consideração ao `FROM:` mas na fonte da mensagem está bem explicito quem enviou e geralmente segue com `utilizador@servidor.com` apesar de aparecer no `FROM:` `alguemr@example.com`.